# Carousel works in Bootply but not my site

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I was working on a sample with the bootply.com website

[Sample](http://www.bootply.com/HZFtavOOxT)

And it works fine.  When I port the code over to my live site I get this weird behavior when both divs show up during the transition.

I can not spot the difference.

[image]

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myCarousel").carousel({
      interval: 3000
    });
}); // document.ready
```

CSS

```
.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
     -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
      -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
       -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
          transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
}

.carousel.vertical .active {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .next {
  top: 40px;
}

.carousel.vertical .prev {
  top: -40px;
}

.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.left {
  top: -40px;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.right {
  top: 40px;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x40/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=First+Slide"
            class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x40/00FF00/FFFFFF/?text=Second+Slide"
            class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x40/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=Third+Slide"
            class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Site HTML

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="LegalBanner.css">

</head>
<body>


        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical">
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x40/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=First+Slide"
                class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x40/00FF00/FFFFFF/?text=Second+Slide"
                class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x40/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=Third+Slide"
                class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="LegalBanner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
.vertical .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This carousel wrapper stretches the entire height (beyond what one slide would would). So you'll see the new slide being appended to the bottom and it sliding up (normally all this would be hidden because of an `overflow: hidden` on the same element)

Comment: That fixed it, Thank you.  I just don't know why the Bootply website doesn't have that issue.